# Blank page after building with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, deployment

i have a problem. When i build my React project using `npm run build && serve-s build` the project build running a blank page.

I search on Google this problem and the community fix using `"homepage": "."` in the **package.json**, then i tried set this flag, but nothing. I tried too using `"homepage": "mysite.com/site/app/build"` (this is path to my project).

And my **package.json** includes `"homepage": "."`

I'm using `react-router-dom` for routes managment and i tried change the  `BrwoserRouter` to `HashRouter` and add `basename="/"` to `BrwoserRouter` and nothing.

Someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

homepage is not the path to the project. It is the home page of your website or you can say the address where it will be visible, so your homepage should be something like-

`homepage: "https://yourdomain.com"`

And pls give more detail so we can help

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by doing two things:

1. In my package.json I included: "homepage": "."
2. In my src/index.js file, where I imported `BrwoserRouter`, I removed the **exact** prop:

   Before: <Route **exact={true}** path="/" component={App} />

   After: `<Route path="/" component={App} />`

It worked for me!